# I don't understand: for (var node = list; node; node = node.rest)

Tags: javascript

The exercise below is based on the book "Eloquent Javascript." The function **listToArray** takes in a **linked list** (or a nested set of objects) as an argument. I'm having trouble visualizing how the for loop in this function works. And why is the condition just "node"?

```js
function arrayToList(array) {
  var list = null;
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    list = {
      value: array[i],
      rest: list
    };
  }
  return list;
}

function listToArray(list) {
  var array = [];
  for (let node = list; node; node = node.rest) {
    array.push(node.value);
  }
  return array;
}

console.log(arrayToList([10, 20]));
// → {value: 10, rest: {value: 20, rest: null}}
console.log(listToArray(arrayToList([10, 20, 30])));
// → [10, 20, 30]
```

Comment: The condition runs while `node` is truthy. Once `node.rest` is falsey, the loop ends.

Comment: The second portion of this `for` is the condition to be tested to see if another iteration of the loop should be carried out. When a single value is used (`node` here), it simply evaluates the variable and converts it to a Boolean. If the result is `true`, the loop goes again. if `false` it doesn't

Comment: Putting `node` as the condition is essentially the same as writing `node != null` in this case.

Comment: @Lain Not quite. It runs **while** `node` is [`truthy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) (not "truesy").  It runs **until** `node` is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy).

Comment: @Lain You wrote "truesy".

Comment: `for(setup;enterloopTrueFalseCondition;doThisAfterEachIterationAndThenCheckCondition)` - kinda in psudo-english... :)

Comment: `for(setup;condition;after)` - setup: can be index=0, condition: can be index<array.length; after: can be increment index, such as in index++.  First, setup is performed.  Second, if condition is true, body of loop is executed.  Third, after is performed, and go back to Second.  Once second is false (could be right-away) go to code after for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you are right, the condition is `node`. But this is like

```js
if (node) {
    doSomething();
}
```

It checks if `node` is "defined" (not `undefined` or `null`)

So let's go step by step through this example:

1. `node = {value: 10, rest: {value: 20, rest: null}}` and `10` (`value`) gets pushed to `array`
2. `node = {value: 20, rest: null}`, because the new `node` is the `rest` of the old `node`; `20` gets pushed to `array`
3. `node = null` → stop here since condition (`node === undefined`) is not fulfilled

Comment: It's actually `node !== null`

Comment: @Barmar: actually, it is `!!node`

Comment: @knittl In this algorithm, `node` is either an object or `null`. So while there are other ways to express the condition more generally, here all that matters is whether `node !== null` is true. The answer has this backwards (it says `===`) and refers to `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I think conditions like `node` are ambiguous, and can lead to unexpected behavior, with little benefit.

Essentially the condition is actually `node != null`, as that is the seed value of the other function. I would recommend making this explicit in any code you write. For example with a language like Go, only Boolean values are allowed for conditions. This can make for more readable code, while perhaps not as "golfed".

Comment: I second this. It sucks to maintain code and not to be sure whether some feature was intended or by accident.

Comment: Well, in fact the condition is actually `!!node`, which tests the value to be truthy. This condition can be rejected by several distinct values: false, 0, empty string, null, and undefined.