# Convert a list to array in JavaScript - how to make sense of this for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am given a list -

```
let listA = {value: 10, rest: {value: 20, rest: { value: 30, rest: null }}}
```

I need to convert it into an array -

```
[10, 20, 30]
```

[I used this for loop to go over the keys in list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZT6ME.png)

It did not work. Eloquent JS book uses this for loop -

```
 let array = [];
  for (let node = list; node; node = node.rest){
    array.push(node.value);
```

I am a beginner. I have only encountered simple for loops such as -

```
for(let i=0; i <= array.length; i++)
```

and similar versions.

What is happening with this for loop syntax ?

[This for loop works but don't know how](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40zMT.png)

Comment: No code as pictures please. Code is already text, so it can be easily copied and pasted, no need to take screenshots of it.

Comment: On a related topic: avoid "for...in" loops when iterating over objects. Prefer ["for...of"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

Comment: Someone already had answered this. [This link can help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62645736/i-dont-understand-for-var-node-list-node-node-node-rest)

Comment: Thank you everyone. I am new here and this helps a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Your "list" is a linked list. It is modeled as recursively nested objects. You need either a recursive algorithm or keep track of your current "stack" manually when writing in iterative form.

```
let array = [];
for (let node = list; node; node = node.rest) {
  array.push(node.value);
}
```

Takes the first object, pushes it into the array, then lets the current object point to `node.rest` (the inner, nested object) and repeats this until the current object no longer points anywhere (`node` is shorthand for `!!node`: it tests the value to be truthy. Not quite right, but you can think of it as `node != null`).

If you are not accustomed to non-indexed for-loops, it can easily be translated into a while loop with the same behavior:

```
let array = [];
let node = list;
while (node) { // shorthand for `!!node`: tests the value to be truthy
  array.push(node.value);
  node = node.rest;
}
```

The variable `node` assumes the following values in order:

1. `{ value: 10, rest: { value: 20, rest: { value: 30, rest: null } } }`
2. `{ value: 20, rest: { value: 30, rest: null } }`
3. `{ value: 30, rest: null }`
4. `null`

Comment: Well written and nicely documented!

Comment: As a possible improvement I would suggest to change the second term in the `for(...)` expression to: `node.value!==undefined`. This would make it more reliable in cases where the property `rest` was something else than `null` or a nested object, like e. g.: `rest:"none"` or `rest:[]`.

Comment: @CarstenMassmann it could, but the question was about why one loop worked and the other doesn't. The input is specified to contain `rest:null` for the last node, so I don't see any reason to harden the code against unexpected inputs.

Comment: Yes - absolutely right! This answer fits the question 100% and I upvoted it. My comment was meant as an improvement to the original code in the question. Just as some "food for thought".  ;-)  In my opinion it is _always_ a good idea to "harden the code" against unexpected inputs. :D

Answer (score 0):

Your input object is nested json object with value key and rest as next object.

```
{value: 10, rest: {value: 20, rest: { value: 30, rest: null }}}
```

For loop that you have put is iterating over the nested object

1. In first iteration it takes the root object pushing value 10 to the
   array.
2. In 2nd iteration it takes the first nested object reading value 20
   and it pushes it to the array.
3. In 3rd iteration it reads next nested object and pushes value 30 to
   the array.

￼